# Is there a Wordpress alternative for Mobile Apps?

Tags: android, open-source, iphone-app, wordpress, mobile

Wordpress offers an opensource platform to help create websites and webapps from templates and then also to customize and personalize it. Is there something similar for the Mobile App world?

I have also researched many paid version of solutions which allow wordpress sites/webapps to be converted into mobile apps, is there an dependable opensource solution for the same?

Kindly suggest.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've used the [Ionic Framework](https://ionicframework.com/) in the past. Mentioning Wordpress makes me think that you are a web developer therefore Ionic is a very good framework for you as you can use web programming languages to build app your application.

Comment: Were you able to pull all the other features of WordPress, such as plugins? The WP-API is great for pulling in content like posts and pages, but it starts to get difficult if you want to do anything else. Hence asking.

Comment: Ionic framework do have plugins if that's what you are asking. https://market.ionicframework.com/plugins

Comment: No I meant can we pull the plugins that I have already used on the WP site into the app using Ionic?

Comment: No you won't be able to do this. I don't believe that there is another platform except WordPress that is compatible with WordPress plugins. If you know the process behind the progress though you can code it into your app.

Comment: Actually AppPress does provide some integration in that regard. I haven't implemented it largely hence cannot comment on the full scale feasibility of it. But honestly I am looking for alternative platform which is to mobile apps as WP is to websites.

Comment: If support for WP plug-ins is a deal breaker, then you need to update your question to say so. Please read [ask]